# Boarding pass (pk.pass file) - How to fix false time on iphone reminder after switch of the time zone

Tags: ios, notifications, timezone, wallet

The reminder shows a wrong time on my boarding pass after I changed the time zone. E.g. if you want to enter a return flight from a foreign time zone.

The Reminder seems to convert the time zone again although the time was already specified in the local time in the JSON pkpass file.

Depending on the time zone, the reminder may display a delayed time.

What I have already tried (tested on the IPhone 6 and 7):

1. **ignoresTimeZone** property to set to true - unfortunately didn't work. But it could also be that I set it in a wrong place (I set it to the highest level).
2. i set the **location** of the airport but also this did not work. But it could also be that my test (my smartphone was local by me).
3. **researched everything possible on the internet** and unfortunately very often found the same problem but unfortunately no solution.

```
{  
   "passTypeIdentifier":"xxxx.xxxx.xx",
   "formatVersion":1,
   "serialNumber":"xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx",
   "description":"my boarding pass",
   "organizationName":"my organization",
   "teamIdentifier":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "relevantDate":"2019-07-12T15:00:00+02:00",
  "locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : -12.3456,
      "latitude" : 78.9101112
    }
  ],
   "relevantText":"this is a test",
   "foregroundColor":"rgb(0,0,0)",
   "backgroundColor":"rgb(194,200,155)",
   "labelColor":"rgb(200,95,25)",
   "boardingPass":{  
      "headerFields":[  
     ...
      ],
      "primaryFields":[  
         {  
            "key":"origin",
            "label":"yyyyyyy yyyyy",
            "value":"YYY"
         },
         {  
            "key":"destination",
            "label":"xxxxxxxxxx",
            "value":"XXX"
         }
      ],
      "secondaryFields":[  
         {  
            "key":"passenger-name",
            "label":"Name",
            "value":"xxxx xxxx"
         }
      ],
      "auxiliaryFields":[  
         {  
            "key":"flight",
            "label":"Flight",
            "value":"XXXXXX"
         },
         {  
            "key":"date",
            "label":"Date",
            "value":"12Jul"
         },
         {  
            "key":"boarding-time",
            "label":"Boarding",
            "value":"15:00"
         }
      ],
      "backFields":[  
         {  
            "key":"terms",
            "value":"xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx"
         }
      ],
      "transitType":"PKTransitTypeAir"
   },
   "barcode":{  
      ...
   },
   "ignoresTimeZone":true
}
```

It's the same/similar problem like this here  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4529193:
[image: the Problem]
[image: the Problem2]

**The expected result is when the time at the reminder is exact the same as the boarding pass.**

The Remeinder should always remind me with the right time (time which is also on the boarding pass) no matter in which time zone I am at the moment.

many thanks for Your help. You are my last hope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Bug.
The problem was my system and the delivered data. The date for the reminder was always wrong (wrong time zone).

**So if you have a similar problem, so check and validate your input first.**